# Gitlab: how auto close the older pipeline when a new pipeline starts on the same branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

For the same branch, what will happen if the newer pipelines of a newer commit succeeds before the older finished? 
It means that the deployed service will be covered when the older finish.

It cannot  ensure that the service is deployed with the latest code.

How could I close automatically the older pipeline when a new pipeline starts on the same branch?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the gitlabci API to play with your jobs. I didn't try but i seems to be possible :
*POST /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/cancel*

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#cancel-a-pipelines-jobs